# Different content depending on the country with the same URL

Tags: seo

I have a web page where I sell products and have the following URL:

```
www.myserver.com/en/xxxxx
```

"/ en" is the language
"/ xxxxxx" references content from the product page

Depending on the user's IP address, I know which country resides and depending on the country the price of the product may vary.

That is, the price of product X in Spain is 39.99 € and the same product in Uruguay is priced at $ 44.

In my code I instruct Google meta tags by price and currency for Spain as follows:

```html
<meta content = "EUR" itemprop = "pricecurrency" />
<meta content = "39.99" itemprop = "price" />
```

And for Uruguay:

```html
<meta content = "USD" itemprop = "pricecurrency" />
<meta content = "44" itemprop = "price" />
```

Is there a way to indicate to Google the country for which is valid the content of the page?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possibly with schema you could put all variations on the page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399128/schema-org-product-with-prices-in-multiple-currencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Google Webmaster Central FAQ:

```
Q: Can I use meta tags to specify geotargeting?
A: Google does not use meta tags when determining geotargeting.
```

https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-internationalisation

Your options to have Google pick this up would be to have a separate landing page for each product offered to each country, or submit a product feed for inclusion into the Google Shopping engine.

Comment: Thanks, on this link I can view questions of Geotargeting, the only way to indicate the valid content for the country is by URL as you say. Thanks @Robert82