# Can I use alternateName more than once?

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

For structured data, can [alternateName](https://schema.org/alternateName) be used more than once on a single thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every property can be used multiple times.

You could even provide multiple `name` properties, but it might make sense to use one `name` property (for the canonical/official name) and one or more `alternateName` properties for all other names.

Examples: [`Person` with several `name`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21365575/1591669), [`Product` with several `color`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22993867/1591669), [`Offer` with several `priceSpecification`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23182834/1591669), [item with several `additionalType`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/81081/17633).

Comment: Now for the $64 question:  is there any way to use alternateName more than once in JSON-LD?

I am hoping to publish a review of an Italian B-movie which has four different titles.

Comment: @PaulKienitz: Yes. [Example with string values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44528609/1591669), [example with node values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30506476/1591669)

Comment: Thanks.  I did eventually find through other sources that you use an array in json-LD for cases where you'd use repeated tags in other formats.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the Schema.org documentation allows to use alternateName property multiple times, using an array, such as

```
"alternateName": [
    "name variation 1",
    "name variation 2",
    "name variation 3"
    ]
```

But in reality, Google does not take more than one variation, and reports an error in Google Rich Results testing tool.

It is better to use "name" property for a canonical, or official name, then use "alternateName" for an alternate name, such as a common misspell or a shorter version of the official name. On top of that, you can use "legalName" for an officially registered name of an organization.