# Can Schema.org Expected Types be collections, too?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

A [Schema.org](https://schema.org) object of type [`Person`](https://schema.org/Person) can have a [`sameAs`](https://schema.org/sameAs) property of type [`URL`](https://schema.org/URL). [According to Google's structured data site](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/social-profile-links), the `sameAs` property can be a single item or an array.

The docs on Schema.org do not mention whether `sameAs` can be a single item or an array. Is this just Google deviating from Schema.org? Or is it the case that all properties in Schema.org can be single items or arrays?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every Schema.org property can have multiple values. It doesn’t necessarily make sense for some properties (e.g., [`birthDate`](http://schema.org/birthDate)), but it’s still allowed.

In JSON-LD:

```json
"sameAs": ["/foo", "/bar"],
```

In Microdata:

```html
<link itemprop="sameAs" href="/foo" />
<link itemprop="sameAs" href="/bar" />
```

In RDFa:

```html
<link property="sameAs" href="/foo" />
<link property="sameAs" href="/bar" />
```

This doesn’t necessarily mean that Google (or any other consumer) supports this for every property, too. So when Google explicitly mentions this in their documentation, you can be sure that the respective search result feature works with multiple values.

Comment: Good to know. Do you have any documentation backing this up?

Comment: Is this supported by rich snippets?