# How can you specify the subject matter of a blog post using Wikidata item URIs?

Tags: schema.org, wikidata, structured-data

I would like to unambiguously describe (by using Wikidata URIs) what the subject matter of a blog post is using Schema.org.

Any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: what have your tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Schema.org’s [`about`](https://schema.org/about) property:

> The subject matter of the content.

While this property expects a `Thing` value, [it’s possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57211562/1591669) to provide a `URL` value.

RDFa examples:

```html
<article typeof="schema:BlogPosting">

  <!-- URL value -->
  <link property="schema:about" href="http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q892" />

</article>
```

```html
<article typeof="schema:BlogPosting">

  <!-- Thing value -->
  <div property="schema:about" typeof="schema:Person" resource="http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q892">
    <meta property="schema:name" content="J. R. R. Tolkien" />
  </div>

</article>
```